# For a function $f(A)$ where $A$ is a matrix prove that the following.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, diagonalization, matrix-decomposition

I have to prove that $f(P^{-1} AP) = P^{-1} f(A) P$, where $A$ is a symmetric matrix and
$$
f(x)=3x^2+2
$$

So far I have done the following:

[image]

Please verify my approach. Also is there an alternative proof? Thanks

Comment: What is $P$? And what have you tried doing so far?

Comment: What is $P$? Also, don't you mean $P^{-1}f(A)P$?

Comment: What is $f$? Domain, codomain, some additional property...?

Comment: I doubt that this is easy, or even possible, for arbitrary functions. For polynomials or functions like $\sin(A)$ or $e^A$ that prove is straight forward. What have you tried?

Comment: @nbubis  yes you are correct i made a mistake there.

Comment: @PhilippSiehr please see my approach

Comment: @ajotatxe f is a function

Comment: Again - what function?

Comment: @PhilippSiehr it can be any function .

Comment: not any function it should have at least some regularity

Answer (score 0):

So it is not any function, but a specific function. And the only part missing is 
$$g(P^{-1}AP) = P^{-1}g(A)P$$
for $g(x)=x^2$. Is that correct?

In detail we have: 
\begin{align*}
P^{-1}g(A)P &= P^{-1}A^2P \\
&= P^{-1}AAP\\
&= P^{-1}AIAP\\
&= P^{-1}APP^{-1}AP\\
&= (P^{-1}AP)^2\\
&=g(P^{-1}AP)
\end{align*}

Comment: it doesnt has to be g(x) = x^2 ... it could be any function. I just solved for an example. can it be generalized?

Comment: Your question specifically states that $f(x)=3x^2+2$. In the general case for `any function`. Be more specific, as you have been told several times in the comments.